# is it possible to connect discord OAuth with AWS cognito using user pools?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I'm trying to connect discord OAuth with cognito using openID but it's not working. does anyone have experience with this?

I already tried to use openID connect under identity providers in my user pool from cognito, but every time I tried to login the discord website says invalid scope:openid

Comment: I believe it is: I found the following documentation that might help you get started... I'm also interested in employing this authentication technique, so let me know if you work it out. If I end up implementing this before you do I'll be sure to come back here and share. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html and... https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people suggesting to use this, which is forked from the GitHub implementation and changed to use Discord.
https://github.com/qwerqy/discord-cognito-openid-wrapper